# Optimizing and accounting for edge cases in Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I just recently wrote a program to simulate how multicast routing works.

The program uses a weighted graph to represent the network and simply runs it through the algorithm.

I would like to know if there is a better and more efficient way of going about this.

Here are my classes:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sdfghj;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import sdfghj.WeightedGraph;
public class smallNetworkSimulation
{
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
       final WeightedGraph t = new WeightedGraph (6);
       t.setLabel (0, "A");
       t.setPort(0);
       t.setLabel (1, "B");
       t.setPort(1);
       t.setLabel (2, "C");
       t.setPort(2);
       t.setLabel (3, "D");
       t.setPort(3);
       t.setLabel (4, "E");
       t.setPort(4);
       t.setLabel (5, "F");
       t.setPort(5);


   //Small network link establishment 
       int cost;
       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (0,1, cost);
       t.addEdge (1,0, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (0,5, cost);
       t.addEdge (5,0, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);  
       t.addEdge (1,2, cost);
       t.addEdge (2,1, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (1,3, cost);
       t.addEdge (3,1, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (1,5, cost);
       t.addEdge (5,1, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (3,5, cost);
       t.addEdge (5,3, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (2,3, cost);
       t.addEdge (3,2, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (4,3, cost);
       t.addEdge (3,4, cost);

       cost = (int) (Math.random() * 100 +1);
       t.addEdge (4,2, cost);
       t.addEdge (2,4, cost);

       t.print();
       ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
       routingTable(x,t);
    }
    public static void routingTable(ArrayList path, WeightedGraph t)
    {

        final int [] pred = Dijkstra.dijkstra (t, 0);
        System.out.println("\t\t\t Outcoming Port \t|\t Outcoming Label \t|\t IncomingPort \t\t|\t Incoming Label");
           for (int n=0; n<6; n++) 
           {
                path = Dijkstra.printPath (t, pred, 0, n);
                ArrayList path1 = Dijkstra.printPathPorts (t, pred, 0, n);
                int j;

                System.out.println("\t\t  " + t.getLabel(0) + " to : " + t.getLabel(n) + " is " + path);
                for(int i=0; i<path.size()-1;i++)
                {
                    j=i+1;
                    if(!(path.get(i).equals(path.get(path.size()-1))))
                    {                     
                        System.out.println("\t\t|\t\t" + path1.get(i) + "\t\t|\t\t" + path.get(i) + "\t\t|\t\t"
                        + path1.get(j) + "\t\t|\t\t" + path.get(j)); 
                    }
                }
            }
        //ex path: [0,4,5]
    }
}
```

graph class:

```
package sdfghj;

public class WeightedGraph 
{
    private final int [][]  edges;  // adjacency matrix
    private final Object [] labels;
    private final Object [] ports;

    public WeightedGraph (int n) 
    {
       edges  = new int [n][n];
       labels = new Object[n];
       ports = new Object[n];
    }

    public int size() 
    { 
        return labels.length; 
    }

    public void setPort(int vertex)
    {
        ports[vertex] = vertex;
    }
    public Object getPort(int vertex)
    {
        return vertex;
    }
    public void   setLabel (int vertex, Object label) 
    { 
        labels[vertex]=label; 
    }
    public Object getLabel (int vertex)               
    { 
        return labels[vertex]; 
    }

    public void    addEdge    (int source, int target, int w)  
    { 
        edges[source][target] = w; 
    } //Adds respective edge to matrix with given weight w.

    public boolean isEdge     (int source, int target)  
    { 
        return edges[source][target]>0; 
    }

    public int  getWeight  (int source, int target)  
    { 
        return edges[source][target]; 
    }

    public int [] neighbors (int vertex) 
    {
       int count = 0;
       for (int i=0; i<edges[vertex].length; i++) 
       {
          if (edges[vertex][i]>0) count++;
       }
       final int[]answer= new int[count];
       count = 0;
       for (int i=0; i<edges[vertex].length; i++) 
       {
          if (edges[vertex][i]>0) 
          answer[count++]=i;
       }
       return answer;
    }

    public void print () 
    {
       for (int j=0; j<edges.length; j++) 
       {
          System.out.print (labels[j]+": ");
          for (int i=0; i<edges[j].length; i++) 
          {
             if (edges[j][i]>0) System.out.print (labels[i]+": Cost : "+edges[j][i]+" ");
          }
          System.out.println ();
       }
   }
}
```

and Dijkstra's algorithm

```
package sdfghj;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static sdfghj.smallNetworkSimulation.routingTable;

  public class Dijkstra 
  {
  // Dijkstra's algorithm to find shortest path from s to all other nodes
      public static int [] dijkstra (WeightedGraph G, int s) 
      {
        final int [] dist = new int [G.size()];  // shortest known distance from "s"
        final int [] pred = new int [G.size()];  // preceeding node in path
        final boolean [] visited = new boolean [G.size()]; // all false initially

        for (int i=0; i<dist.length; i++) 
        {
            dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // all values initially set to max
        }
        dist[s] = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<dist.length; i++) 
        {
            final int next = minVertex (dist, visited);
            visited[next] = true;

       // The shortest path to next is dist[next] and via pred[next].

            final int [] n = G.neighbors (next);
            for (int j=0; j<n.length; j++) 
            {
                final int v = n[j];
                final int d = dist[next] + G.getWeight(next,v);
                if (dist[v] > d) 
                {
                    dist[v] = d;
                    pred[v] = next;
                }
            }
        }
        return pred;  // (ignore pred[s]==0!)
    }

    private static int minVertex (int [] dist, boolean [] v) 
    {
        int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int y = -1;   // graph not connected, or no unvisited vertices
        for (int i=0; i<dist.length; i++) 
        {
            if (!v[i] && dist[i]<x) {y=i; x=dist[i];}
        }
        return y;
    }
    public static ArrayList printPathPorts (WeightedGraph G, int [] pred, int source, int destination) 
    {

        final java.util.ArrayList path1 = new java.util.ArrayList();
        int x = destination;
        while (x!=source) 
        {
            path1.add(0, G.getPort(x));
            x = pred[x];
        }
        path1.add (0, G.getLabel(source));
    return path1;
    }
    public static ArrayList printPath (WeightedGraph G, int [] pred, int source, int destination) 
    {
        final java.util.ArrayList path = new java.util.ArrayList();
        int x = destination;
        while (x!=source) 
        {
            path.add (0, G.getLabel(x));
            x = pred[x];
        }
        path.add (0, G.getLabel(source));
        System.out.println(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

How could I implement this so that I increase its adaptability? As it is right now, it only accepts Node 0 and the source and it breaks when I try any other Node. Negative weights are also a no go.

Also, feel free to comment on anything else, i.e formatting, variable names, redundancy.

Comment: Are all edges bidirectional, or do they just happen to be that way in your example?

Comment: The graph was set to be bidirectional. 

using the following 

    t.addEdge (0,1, cost);

    and

    t.addEdge (1,0, cost);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `int [] pred` is not initialized properly.

This field currently defaults to 0, which means that the preceding node for all other nodes is set to node 0 on initialization. Which means all nodes with an unreachable predecessor are linked via node 0 in the output, yielding an incorrect path even if there wasn't one.

### Negative weights

That's a simple one - it's not supported by Dijkstra's algorithm. Not relevant to your problem though, as negative costs don't occur in a Multicast network. So no need to choose an more expensive algorithm for this edge case.

### Using Dijkstra's algorithm for Multicast

While this works, and you did in fact manage to call Dijkstra only once, that's not how Multicast works.

For multicast, you want a minimum spanning tree including all recipients, as you want the minimize the cumulative to all recipients with regard to late package duplication. This yields different results with Dijkstra, as Dijkstra will happily discard expensive edges for one route, even though they are used anyway for another one, effectively requiring both routes to be traversed now and doubling the cumulative costs.

See [Use Dijkstra's to find a Minimum Spanning Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909281/use-dijkstras-to-find-a-minimum-spanning-tree) for an extended discussion as to why that isn't the same.

Be warned that calculating a spanning tree only works for an undirected graph, not a directed one such as yours.

### Not supporting costs of 0

This is a bug. A cost of 0 is perfectly valid, both as an input for Dijkstra, and as a cost when finding routes. Think e.g. of routing between local bridges, which has a cost so low, that you can't fit it into the metric.

Choose a different default value for `int [][]  edges`.

### Dense versus spare graphs

Your graph is obviously sparse, and will be for the majority of networks you are applying this algorithm to. This means there is no need to store the full matrix, using an array of arrays is perfectly sufficient.

This also reduces `int [] neighbors (int vertex)` from scanning the table, to simply returning a direct reference on the list of neighbors.

In return this requires resizing the inner array when inserting a new edge, but this is a rare case.

### Using a flat array for `int [] dist`

This has the direct disadvantage that `int minVertex (int [] dist, boolean [] v)` now needs to perform a full sweep of that array every single time it want's to extract the minimum.

Use a `PriorityQueue` instead, the added memory overhead is worth it. You don't even need to insert yet unseen nodes into that queue yet.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So what should I be defaulting int [] pred, to?

Comment: I would recommend making `int [] pred` default to the corresponding node itself. This causes the fewest problems. Just make sure that `printPathPorts` and `printPath` are aware of this special value and do not fall into an infinite loop.

Comment: Ah, okay! So, the priorityQueue has been implemented, it now takes costs 0, and int [] pred defaults to the node itself. Now, would you know why the code breaks for any non-zero source nodes?

Comment: No, I don't know that. When you say "it breaks", please be more specific. If there is an exception thrown for a specific edge case, or the code exhibits strange behavior, debug it. For endless loops, use a debugger to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: I like to use the word break when it's something I can't quite understand. The program never finishes its exectute. I have tried letting it run for an hour and nothing. It prints out the link paths but once it actually goes into the algorithm it falls into a black hole.

Comment: Then run it with a debugger and just hit the "pause" button any time. It will stop at a specific location, and you can then exhibit the memory content, respectively step through to see where it stucks.

Comment: My IDE crashes whenever I try running a stack trace through the debugger.

Comment: Then just set a breakpoint before the algorithm and go step by step. Now I'm really curios where you got the IDE to crash, because I see nothing in there which could possibly cause a stack overflow or anything like it, as there isn't even any recursion.

Comment: @DDisciple Are you entirely sure it's crashing INSIDE the algorithm, and not by chance in `printPath`?

Comment: Thats exactly why I am so confused. It did not even give me a stackoverflow, which is what I would expect if it used up all the available stack memory but it just crashed without any warnings lol

Comment: yes, it crashes once it creates an instance of Dijkstras. You can try and run it to see for yourself

Comment: Can you please upload your latest version of the source somewhere? Then I'll try. Preferably on https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Oh, I have not had the chance to type the improvements yet, I am at work so I wrote it down on paper. It should still produce the same output regardless.

Comment: Anyhow, you provided a lot of help and for that I thank you!

Comment: I can't confirm the crash. It runs perfectly fine for me, apart from the known bugs. You've probably got some other problems with your java compilation process.

Comment: Wait, when you try a different source it prints the table ? meaning, it runs the algorithm ?

Comment: Yes. Works for me for all the source from 0 to 5.